# Error while trying to install python packages

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install various Python packages such as `pandas`, `numpy`, `mlforecast`, `xgboost` etc. The issue is I have two Python versions in my VM: 3.11.6 and 3.12.

When I run the command `print(sys.version())` I get:

```
3.11.6
```

But when I check: `!python --version` I get:

```
3.12.0
```

And when I lookup the kernelspecs using:

```
!jupyter kernelspec list
```

I get:

```
Available kernels:
   python3   C:\Python311\share\jupyter\kernels\python3
```

And when I check the sys path:

```
sys.path
['C:\\Users\\myname\\Downloads',
 'C:\\Python311\\python311.zip',
 'C:\\Python311\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python311\\Lib',
 'C:\\Python311',
 '',
'C:\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages',
'C:\\Python311\\Lib]]site-packages\\win32',
'C:\\Python311\\Lib]]site-packages\\win32\\lib',
'C:\\Python311\\Lib]]site-packages\\pythonwin']
```

Both kernelspec and path point to 3.11. But when I try to install say `pandas`

```
pip install pandas
```

I get:

```
Error: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\Python312\\Scripts\\f2py.exe'
```

Looks like the installation is trying to happen in Python 3.12. Could someone please let me know who to make sure that I am using 3.11, more so because some of the packages are not compatible with Python 3.12 yet, so I need to stick to 3.11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Direct Use

You should be able to use it with

```
python3.11 -m pip
```

However you might want to change alias if you only use 3.11 at the moment. See https://www.baeldung.com/linux/default-python3

## In Virtual Environment

You should consider working in a venv especially when you have more than one python version installed. https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

```
python3.11 -m venv ./VENVPATH
source ./VENVPATH/bin/activate
pip install numpy
```

Comment: Could you please let me know what's `-m` for?

Comment: it stands for module -> used to call the main entrypoint of the pip module.  Check out https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/getting-started/

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your pip and setup tools packages are up-to-date. You can upgrade them using the following commands in your command prompt or terminal:

```py
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
python -m pip install --upgrade setuptools
```